# I am getting mcs not found error for only one project other projects are running fine

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using Emgu.CV.Monotouch library project when I am going to build only this project I am getting below error,other projects are working fine in Xamarin studio.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Xamarin.ObjcBinding.CSharp.targets: Error: Tool exited with code: 1. Output: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs: line 4: mcs: command not found
btouch: API binding contains errors.
 (Emgu.CV.MonoTouch)

Comment: I reinstalled mono framework and solved issue.